Screen coordinates in OpenGL shader
I have triangle in screen coordinates, and I have resolution 800x600. How I can put this vertex buffer (triangle with screen coordinates) into OpenGL shader and draw this triangle? Inside shader should need to do conversion from screen coords to NDC?
